# Find the value of $x$ of the shape below

Tags: geometry

I don't really know how to do this, and my teacher didn't explain it as well. 
[image]
This is the shape.

Comment: $x=180-(90-65)+(90-80)$.

Comment: Assuming that the two verticals are indeed parallel, draw a perpendicular to both and consider the triangle formed with the sides of angle $x$.

Comment: Does it need to be so complicated that we need to use triangles?  Draw a third line parallel to both which passes through the vertex for the angle $x$.  We have as a result subdivided the angle $x$ as the sum of two smaller angles.  What is the part on the left?  On the right?  Use the definition of parallel lines.  That being said, @Jack did you accidentally use a plus when you should have used a minus the second time?  It should simply be $65^\circ+80^\circ$

Answer (score 1):

Taking a step back from the technical answers provided in comments, when you deal with a maths textbook question, think about what information you have in hand.  Here, one 'special' thing you have is a pair of parallel lines.  Thus think about what you have learnt about it (corresponding angles on parallel lines are equal) and how you may use this to solve the problem.

Draw a third vertical line through x, left part of x is 65∘ and right part is 80∘ . Angle x is the sum: 145∘.